# Do League of Legends Ranked Fives teams face series for promotion?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am on several ranked fives teams and don't recall having to complete any series. Not sure if it is because our MMR is high or because series are non-existent in ranked teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually because of the MMR.

You will realize when playing the placements of your ranked team and loose many of them and get ranked badly, but then win every game you will skip some promotions. But the higher you climb the more you loose (mostly) and you will stop skipping the promos.

Obviously there are no tools to calculate your team MMR officially but it is definitely based on the soloQ rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in solo you have to win a series to rank up. You probably have not reached that point with a team yet, or just did not notice.
Remember that you have to reach quite a lot of points before entering a series.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really answer my question. I'm considered a high elo SoloQ player so I've been in my fair share of promotion series in SoloQ.  I was hoping for something definitive that answered whether or not they exist in ranked fives.  The four of five teams that I am on haven't had the need to complete a series.

Comment: @Blurn It is a definite answer. Just like in SoloQ you need to win a series to rank up, they do exist and that is exactly what I told you.